# iOS: Switching apps after user clicks ADBannerView causes OpenGL crash

Tags: ios, opengl-es, iad, adbannerview, glkview

I have a GLKViewController subclass implementation, with an ADBannerView as a subview.  Ads load and render just fine.  The OpenGL application also works fine.  When you click on an Ad, the popup appears.  The GLKViewController has the default pause-on-resign behavior enabled.

If you set a breakpoint on GLKViewController's setPaused, you will notice that **setPaused:NO gets called if you switch away from your app** (double-tap home and pick another app) **while the ad popup is visible**.  The behavior only occurs when an ADBannerView popup is visible, not if you switch away from the app otherwise.

I am able to reproduce the above behavior with even the default OpenGL template app generated by Xcode 7 in iOS 9.1.

1) Is this normal?

2) For me this causes consistent reproducible crashes because after setPaused:NO is called, the GLKViewController is redrawn, which causes OpenGL operations to occur while the app is in the background.  The app is (correctly) killed at this point.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround is to discard calls to `setPaused:NO` as follows when the application is not active.  This appears to work fine but why this is happening at all is confusing me.

```c
- (void)setPaused:(BOOL)paused
{
    long appState = (long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
    if (!paused && (appState != 0)) {
        NSLog(@"setPaused - REJECTING Unpause; %ld", appState);
        return;
    }
    [super setPaused:paused];
}
```